# unable to start docker after upgrading to 1.12 version

Tags: sockets, docker, centos

I have upgraded to docker version 1.12 running on centos 7.2 and I no longer can start the daemon with both unix and tcp sockets, the command used to look like this in the /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service

ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// -H tcp://127.0.0.1:4243 where I have amended the tcp socket info.

now in the new version it looks like

ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd

if i add just the tcp socket, unix socket is not working and i can only use docker via api while cli stops working
what is the best way to start this version with both sockets operational?

Thank You in advance

Comment: Did you try installing via the Docker install docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/ ? You could try removing what you have any reinstall with that.

Comment: thank you, thats the doc i followed. it looks like the syntax has changed in this new version. I was doing a clean install following the document and than i was trying to amend the startup parameters with what i had previously

Comment: anybody?:) really need to run docker with both options